# Returning a custom type in a PL/SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

My goal is to write either a function or a stored procedure in PL/SQL that returns a table for the user to immediately view. I have dozens of history tables and want to give myself a snapshot of a single users history across all of the tables. but I am running into an error and I am not sure if this is even the best way to do this.

My current approach is to gather all of the information from the tables into a custom "summary table" type and then return it. However I am getting errors when using my custom "userTable" as the type of my out parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetUserSnapShot(myid in Number, numdays in Number,
 myTable out userTable)
AS 
BEGIN
  /*maybe insert a row into the table here?*/
  myTable := null;
END;


DECLARE
   TYPE userChanges IS RECORD (
       historyTable VARCHAR(100),
       historyId NUMBER,
       changeType VARCHAR(6),
       changeDate DATE
     );
  TYPE userTable IS TABLE OF userChanges INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  myTable userTable;
 BEGIN
   GetUserSnapShot(5, 7, myTable);
END;
```

here is the error I get when trying to run this: identifier 'USERTABLE' must be declared which is confusing to me since I have declared userTable

Comment: Why can't you simply return the results of a select query?

Comment: The compiler needs to be able to look up the definition of `userTable` in order to compile the procedure. It can't just be in some script on your desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the type `USERTABLE` in your anonymous block, but the procedure doesn't know what's in your anonymous block and thus can't see the type.

I suggest that it would be best for you to use a package so you can put the record type, table type, and the procedure in the package. An example would be:

```
CREATE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS  -- define the package spec
  TYPE userChanges IS RECORD
    (
    historyTable VARCHAR(100),
    historyId NUMBER,
    changeType VARCHAR(6),
    changeDate DATE
    );

  TYPE userTable IS TABLE OF userChanges
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  PROCEDURE GetUserSnapShot(myid    in     Number,
                            numdays in     Number,
                            myTable in out userTable);
END MY_PACKAGE;

CREATE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE AS  -- define the package body
  PROCEDURE GetUserSnapShot(myid    in     Number,
                            numdays in     Number,
                            myTable in out userTable)
  AS
    rec  userChanges; 
  BEGIN
    rec.historyTable := 'SOMEWHERE';
    rec.historyId    := 1;
    rec.changeType   := 'ABCDEF';
    rec.changeDate   := SYSDATE;

    myTable(1) := rec;
  END;
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

Now you can reference the packaged procedure and type in your anonymous block as:

```
DECLARE
  MY_PACKAGE.myTable userTable;
BEGIN
  MY_PACKAGE.GetUserSnapShot(5, 7, myTable);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: hmmm when I run all of that at once as posted I still get: 

"ORA-06550: line 2, column 11: PLS-00201: identifier 'USERTABLE' must be declared ORA-06550: line 2, column 11: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: line 4, column 25: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed ORA-06550: line 4, column 3: PL/SQL: Statement ignored"

Comment: @jdmneon - use the package name in the anonymous block. ( Write: ) declare myTable my_package.userTable; begin my_package.GetUserSnapshot(5, 7, mytable) ; end;

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - I really like how you used a package for this solution!  Another tiny wee thing: the package body compiles with an error.  In the spec, for GetUserSnapShot there's "myTable out userTable" in the parameter list, whereas in the body, you put "myTable in out userTable". (Thus, I get: "PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor 'GETUSERSNAPSHOT' is declared in a package specification and must be defined in the package body".  Easily amended by adding the word "out" into the package spec code)

Comment: Thanks! I got it working! using you and stefans suggestion, is there a way for me to easily select the results that exist inside that table?

like

DECLARE
  MY_PACKAGE.myTable userTable;
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM MY_PACKAGE.GetUserSnapShot(5, 7, myTable);
END;

Comment: @jdmneon - (in the anonymous block) use a cursor for loop and select * from table( mytable ), similar to the code in the first example @ https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/using-the-table-operator-with-locally-defined-types-in-plsql-12cr1.